# Loading transient field of JPA entity

Tags: jpa

I have an entity with a transient field "limit" which I want to load after calculating it by applying formula on value of another persistent field "rate".How to do that while loading the entity?

Answer (score 5):

You can use JPA lifecycle listeners. You can define listener callback methods inside your entity or in an own class.

Since you want to filter data coming from the DB, you should use the [`PostLoad`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html) callback.

The simplest way to go is to add a listener method to your entity class:

```
  @PostLoad
  public/protected void calcLimit() {
   // calculate limit
  }
```

Comment: No need for the method to be `public` - unless you need to call it from other classes. `

Comment: am I misunderstanding the docs? I have the definition [from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html): `public @interface PostLoad`

Comment: @Tassos since it is a callback method, does any situation arise for calling it from other classes?

Comment: I suppose it **has** to be public - this callback will **always** be called from another class - a facility inside JPA that triggers callbacks. The entity itself should not call this method. The JPA callback facility will belong to a different package than the entity, so protected is not enough.

Comment: @kostja the annotation `@PostLoad` is public; the method it annotates need not be public, as the JPA implementation will call it using reflection. Usually you can leave the actual method protected and call it in every setter so that the computed value remains consistent. Sometimes you want to expose this functionality to other classes; for example because the computation depends on changed values outside the class.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense. Thanks for the explanation, Tassos. I have searched for examples of such listener methods and at least the first dozen was public, at least on SO. Have added the protected option to the example.